# iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode4.5

I wanted to upload my application to Appstore, but i've got some problem with validating it. 
These 3 errors show up every time i try to validate my app:

1. iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7 (-19033)
2. Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
3. Unable to extract entitlements from application: (null) (-19045)

I get same errors no matter what i do. i've tried everything; i've got deployment target set to 4.3, i've also tried with 5.0 6.0 with same results, i've changed my certificates like 5 times, I've tested with settings from similar working applikations, and nothing. I've tried with different architecture code singing and so on. Like i said; i've tried everything with no result. It's worth mentioning that i used drilldownsave sample app as my ground it was build for ios 3.2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem: info.plist -> Executable file with value ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} and behind ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} i must have left a space somehow, when i deleted it everything worked just perfect

Answer (score 1):

Unplug your device when you build the Archive. You are building for a specific device family. You want your Scheme to be building for a generic iOS Device.

[image]

For the other errors, make sure you are properly signing the application with the appropriate certificate. This can be found under:

```
Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Code Signing Identity
```

Comment: i've already done that and it isn't working. Like i said before; i've tested everything in build settings

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Also could you go to Target -> Build Settings -> Architectures -> Release and let me know what value you have there?

Comment: Also, please make sure that Build Active Architectures Only is set to NO.

Comment: I'm using xcode 4.6.1 and i've Build Active Architectures Only set to NO, i've tried with YES as well but still, same results.

Comment: and Architectures->Release is set to Standard (armv7, armv7s) ive tried only with armv7 as well as armv7s, still same thing

Comment: Thanks Ben, your suggestion fixed my mistake -- maybe this can save someone else a few minutes of grief as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue, and it got resolved..

It turned out, that i've different Bundle/Executable name than the project name.

Go to Project > double click Target

Rename it to the Bundle/Executable name, then build for Release/iOS Device

and the Application loader will accept your App.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this article http://www.mindyourcode.com/ios/iphone/iphoneipod-touch-application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture/ you need to add both architectures armv6 and armv7